# How to edit an fact in Ansible

Tags: loops, ansible

I have in my ansible playbook a dict that looks similar to:

```
  "fact_one": true,
  "fact_two": true,
  "disks": [
    {
      "name": "/dev/sda"
    },
    {
      "name": "/dev/sdb"
    },
    {
      "name": "/dev/sdc"
    }
  ],
}
```

So, now i need to do a loop through the disks items and then update each disks entry with a new variable called ID. So, my new dict should looks like:

```
  "fact_two": true,
  "disks": [
    {
      "name": "/dev/sda"
      "id": "id001"
    },
    {
      "name": "/dev/sdb"
      "id": "id002"
    },
    {
      "name": "/dev/sdc"
      "id": "id003"
    }
  ],
}
```

Also, as you can see, my ID is a counter that should be added in +1 each iteration.

How I can write this kind of loop in Ansible ?
I want to update the existing facts and not to create new ones.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is this one:

```
set_fact:
  disks: |
    {% set result = [] %}
    {% for d in disks %} 
    {%   set _ = result.append('name': d.name, 'id': 'id00' + loop.index | str) %}
    {% endfor %}
    {{ result }}
```

or

```
set_fact:
  disks: |
    {% set result = [] %}
    {% for d in disks %} 
    {%   set item = d %}
    {%   set _ = item.update('id': 'id00' + loop.index) | str ) %}        
    {%   set _ = result.append(item) %}
    {% endfor %}
    {{ result }}
```